# How do I return a set of dom elements using JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to render some components ONLY IF some condition is true.

to accomplish that I am using inside render():

```
 return (
  <div className={classes.root}>

    {registrationScreen && (
      **** This is where I want to put the components ****
    )}

  </div>)
```

The components I want to put also have {} inside of them:

```
        <Tabs
         value={value}
         onChange={this.handleChange}
         classes={{ root: classes.tabsRoot, indicator: classes.tabsIndicator }}
       >
         {tabs.map(tab => (
           <Tab
           disableRipple
           classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.tabSelected }}
           label={tab}
           className={classes.fontTab}
         />
         ))}
       </Tabs>
         {value === 0 && 
         <TabContainer>
           <Form razaoSocial={razaoSocial} handleRazaoSocial={handleRazaoSocial}></Form>
         </TabContainer>}
         {value === 1 && 
         <TabContainer>
           Teste
         </TabContainer>}
         {value === 2 && 
         <TabContainer>
           TESTE3
         </TabContainer>}
```

however when I try to place them inside of the if it returns: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the context of that code block at the end?

Comment: can you show all of your code in both render method? and a snapshot of your properties which used in your components?

Comment: Fundamentally, what you describe works: https://plnkr.co/edit/l8fC8DWxsxMkqTVVKTFh?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the components you want to put inside of the condition with a root element. React expected all component to have a root element/parent node. You can use `<Fragment/>` component as a root if you don't want extra element to be render. You can import Fragment from 'react' like this `import { Fragment } from 'react';` then use it for the component you want to place in the condition block

```
<Fragment>
    <Tabs
     value={value}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     classes={{ root: classes.tabsRoot, indicator: classes.tabsIndicator }}
   >
     {tabs.map(tab => (
       <Tab
       disableRipple
       classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.tabSelected }}
       label={tab}
       className={classes.fontTab}
     />
     ))}
   </Tabs>
     {value === 0 && 
     <TabContainer>
       <Form razaoSocial={razaoSocial} handleRazaoSocial={handleRazaoSocial}></Form>
     </TabContainer>}
     {value === 1 && 
     <TabContainer>
       Teste
     </TabContainer>}
     {value === 2 && 
     <TabContainer>
       TESTE3
     </TabContainer>}
</Fragment>
```